# Networking player bug UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

**Hello i have a spawning problem when i start google service RealTime  both player are lagging and one player is bugged into ground collider. Here is Animation:**

[Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tazqf.gif)

Here is my sending script from client:

```
void Update()
{

    if (player == PlayerOne) {       
    string PlayerOneData = "PlayerOne" + ":" + player.transform.position.x + ":" + player.transform.position.y;
    byte[] PlayerOneDataArr = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(PlayerOneData);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessageToAll(false, PlayerOneDataArr);
    // Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().setTarget(PlayerOne.transform);
    textik.text = "PlayerOne upload " + PlayerOneData;
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            double halfScreen = Screen.width / 2.0;
            if (touchPosition.x < halfScreen)
            {
                player.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (touchPosition.x > halfScreen)
            {
                player.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }
    }
    else if (player == PlayerTwo)
    {
        string PlayerTwoData = "PlayerTwo" + ":" + player.transform.position.x + ":" + player.transform.position.y;
        byte[] PlayerTwoDataArr = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(PlayerTwoData);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessageToAll(false, PlayerTwoDataArr);
        //Camera.main.GetComponent<CameraFollow>().setTarget(PlayerTwo.transform);
        textik.text = "PlayerTwo upload" + PlayerTwoData;
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            Vector2 touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            double halfScreen = Screen.width / 2.0;

            //Check if it is left or right?
            if (touchPosition.x < halfScreen)
            {
                player.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else if (touchPosition.x > halfScreen)
            {
                player.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 10 * Time.deltaTime);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And this is my receive function:

```
public void OnRealTimeMessageReceived(bool IsReliable, string SenderId, byte[] data)
{

    string position = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
    string[] raw = position.Split(new string[] { ":" }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (!IsReliable)
    {
        if (raw[0] == "PlayerOne")
        {
            PlayerOne.transform.position = new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(raw[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(raw[2]));
            textik2.text = "PlayerOne PRIJAL " + position;
        }
        if (raw[0] == "PlayerTwo")
        {
            PlayerTwo.transform.position=new Vector2(System.Convert.ToSingle(raw[1]), System.Convert.ToSingle(raw[2]));
            textik2.text = "PlayerTWO prijal " + position;
        }
    }
}
```

My prefab are seetup as :

[Prefab Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjPxC.png)

Thanks for any Ideas or any help

Comment: Is this a 'solve my bug' question? What is the question it self? Do you want us to debug for you?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

How often are you sending data? Make sure you are not sending too often. Make sure you interpolate between transmitted positions.

I can recommend Unitys basic networking example:

https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/network-manager?playlist=29690

You can get it to work in 10 minutes. No server needed

Comment: I send it every frame but it dont solve my problem with bugging another player to ground prefabs started at same position with small space between each.And i dont know how to solve it i also read your link